# How to declare / define once and use map list in two classes in program?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm developing a program, in C++11, in which I need to use a C++ STL map in two classes.
The map has, in the 2 places used, the same list of keys and values.

These classes are used in different parts of the program:

```
// in other part of the program
void check_something()
{
    // the size of the list can be 100, 200 or ...
    map<string, string> amap{
        {"something", "nothing"},
        {"key", "value"},
    };

    SameClass sc{amap};
    // use sc
}

// in other part of the program
void check_other_thing()
{
    // the size of the list can be 100, 200 or ...
    map<string, string> amap_2{
        {"something", "nothing"},
        {"key", "value"},
    };

    SameClass sx{amap_2};
    // use sx
}
```

For now this works (for testing), but I'd like to know (for maintenance and optimization) how to declare and define once and then use the map wherever I need in the program?

Do I need to create a class or struct or function that put the map in a shared_ptr<> and return the map?

I don't want to use global variables!

Comment: If whatever you're going to wrap around it just makes it a glorified global variable, I recommend a global variable over that. Is this map constant, or is it actually modified from one or more parts of the program? That's where you really need to worry.

Comment: like it or not, your maps are in fact global variables.

Comment: Is the map constant, or can sx and sc change their own copy ?  And antoher question:  is the map used only by SameClass or also by different objects ?

Comment: does this list need to be mutable? If not, then you can just make it a global variable that is accessible to both parts of the code.

Comment: @chris the map list don't change (is not a constant), it is there to provide a list of keys - values to use like a database by the two classes.

Comment: @fm21, If it doesn't change and it isn't a constant, make it a constant. One of the major problems with globals is when two separate parts of the program are affected by one another through that global, making it really hard to ensure everything works correctly. Constant globals don't have that problem since you can't change them, and thus one piece of code can't affect the other.

Comment: I edit the code of the question to explain better what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your variable WHEREVER in the program, we're talking about global variable, which you don't want to use (and it's good!).

Another way do this is create class with static variable, which works like globals, but doesn't create name collisions

```
class Variables
{
private:
    Variables () {} // to prevent instantiation, which makes no sense
public:
    static map<string , int> myMap;
    static float numba;
};

float Variables::numba = 0;
map<string , int> Variables::myMap = map<string, int>;
//somehow initialize your static variables
```

And you use it like this `float var = Variables::numba`

---

You could also have function returning reference to your variable and then store it as a pointer. This is in fact better idea, because you won't be using any kind of globals.

So create your map somewhere and just pass it to your object

```
void setMap(map<string, string> &map) //note ampersand, it has to be a reference
{
   mMap = map //where mMap means member variable in your class
}
```

If you want your all your SameClass object to use the exact same map, make it static variable.

Comment: +1 I basically agree with this idea. But Variables::myMap is not a pointer, so you don't do `new()` on it.

Comment: Right my bad, too much java :D Thank you, I'll fix this.

Answer (score 1):

As the many commenters have suggested, there's nothing wrong with *constant* globals.  Globals are only problems if they're mutable.  Since you say the data never changes, then simply make them into `const` globals.  However since they have complex constructors, you'll run into the [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html) if they're not function local statics.  So the fixes look like this:

File1:

```
const map<string, string>& amap() {
    static const map<string,string> v {
        {"something", "nothing"},
        {"key", "value"},
    };
    return v;
}
```

File2 (or maybe a header)

```
const map<string, string>& amap();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your map contains a kind of configuration data. I understand that:

- you have only one map that is used everywhere, but it contains the same date everywhere
- that your map isn't constant,  so somehow it should be possible to change it (or to load it at startup).

I propose you a first solution with a simple `dbconfig` class :

```
class dbconfig {
    static map<string, string> amap;  // satic: there's only one of it
public: 
    operator const map<string,string>& () const  
    { return amap; } 
    // may be some functions to maintain the map 
}; 
map<string, string> dbconfig::amap{   // there's only one such map 
        {"something", "nothing"},     // and it's only viisble in dbconfig
        {"key", "value"},             // so totally protected
    };
```

The trick is to use a conversion operator, that only gives back a read only constant.  So you'd use it anywhere in the programme, just like:

```
dbconfig cfg;   // local variable.  You don't have to worry about it
SameClass sc{ cfg };   // it whill be automatically converted in a reference to
                       // your single static map.
```

The advantage is that your configuration is really encapsulated in an object.  So you could define some members to manage your map (add or remove keys) if necessary.

As the map is not directly visible to the outside, but only via an operator, you could let the internal management of the dbconfig object evolve, without need to change the code using it.    You could for example keep the map empty when the programme starts, and at the first request, load the data from a config file or whatever.

There is an important open questions however:  shall every using object have its own copy of the map, or shall it refer to the single `dbconfig` map ?

Otherwhise stated:  do you envisage to dynamically change your map content, and want all objects use the latest version ?

Depending on the answer you could define your user-class to keep its own copy of the map:

```
class SameClass {
    map<string, string> mine;
public:
    SameClass (const map<string, string>& m) : mine(m) { // const ref, but local copy
    ... 
    };
```

Or keep using a reference:

```
class SameClass {
    const map<string, string> & mine; // refers to the original. No own copy
public:
    SameClass (const map<string, string>& m) : mine(m) { // const ref   ... 
    }; 
};
```

Comment: I want to put +1 to your question because is good but I don't have enough reputation !

Comment: @fm21 No problem ! Thanks for the feedback !  Regardless of your reputation, if this answer helped you to solve your question, you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

After a week of trying, I finally solve this !

Thanks to all who answer, in wich I based the solution of my problem from the ideas of them.

I create a new header file and call it SetMap.hpp and here is the code:

```
#ifndef SETMAP_HPP
#define SETMAP_HPP

#include <map>
#include <string>

struct SetMap
{
    const std::map<std::string, std::string> mymap{
        {"KEY_HERE","VALUE_HERE"},
    };
};

#endif // SETMAP_HPP
```

And then I include this header whenever I need in my program and initialize the struct:

```
#include "SetMap.hpp"

SetMap sm;
// use as sm.mymap;
SameClass sx{sm.mymap};
```

The constructor of SameClass accept a const map reference, like this:

```
SameClass (const map<string, string> &m);
```

When I need to edit the keys or values (since this map act like a database, in my program), I just need to edit, in one place, the header SetMap.hpp.

That way, there's no use of global variables, because the variable 'mymap' is in scope of the struct.

A class here is not needed, because the object is tiny and by default the variables of the struct are public. Also if there's a need to add other variable of the same "concept" - define and declared once - used whenever you need, just add it to the struct.

Thanks to all who take their time into helping me !